# Confused about modifying NumPy arrays over a for loop

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

My apologies as I am sure something like this has been asked before, I have had a search and cannot find an answer to explain what is going on.

For a NumPy array, for each 'column', I want to modify the value to equal 1 and then output the modified array as well as the original column.

My code looks like this:

```
base_arr = (np.random.rand(4, 10) * 10).astype(np.int32)
array([[3, 7, 8, 2, 6, 7, 5, 4, 1, 1],
       [6, 2, 9, 7, 6, 5, 4, 4, 5, 6],
       [6, 2, 5, 6, 1, 4, 4, 3, 1, 3],
       [5, 1, 7, 8, 7, 7, 8, 7, 2, 1]], dtype=int32)
    
mod_arrs = []
orig_vals = []
def modify_array(orig_array, col_idx):
    mod_arr = orig_array
    mod_arr[:, col_idx] = 1
    return mod_arr, orig_array[:, col_idx]

for i in range(base_arr.shape[1]):
    res = modify_array(base_arr, i)
    mod_arrs.append(res[0])
    orig_vals.append(res[1])
```

My expected output is:

```
mod_arrs = [array([[1, 7, 8, 2, 6, 7, 5, 4, 1, 1],
                   [1, 2, 9, 7, 6, 5, 4, 4, 5, 6],
                   [1, 2, 5, 6, 1, 4, 4, 3, 1, 3],
                   [1, 1, 7, 8, 7, 7, 8, 7, 2, 1]], dtype=int32)),
            array([[3, 1, 8, 2, 6, 7, 5, 4, 1, 1],
                   [6, 1, 9, 7, 6, 5, 4, 4, 5, 6],
                   [6, 1, 5, 6, 1, 4, 4, 3, 1, 3],
                   [5, 1, 7, 8, 7, 7, 8, 7, 2, 1]], dtype=int32),
           ...
           ]
orig_vals = [array([3, 6, 6, 5]), array([7, 2, 2, 1]), ...]
```

However, instead I am getting:

```
mod_arrs = [array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                   [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                   [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                   [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]], dtype=int32),
            array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                   [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                   [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                   [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]], dtype=int32),
             ...
             ]
orig_vals = [array([1, 1, 1, 1]), array([1, 1, 1, 1]), ...]
```

Can anyone explain why this is occurring? I was under the impression that the `orig_array` would not be modified. However, during the for loop I can see the 1s slowly taking over the `orig_array`!

Any explanations would be appreciated. :)

Comment: Of course, there is **only one array**. `mod_arr = orig_array` does not make a new array at all. That simply assigns the object to *another local variable*.

Comment: IOW, `res is base_array` is always true. Furthermore, `res[0]` and `res[1]` create *views* in numpy

Comment: ahh I see! Thank you! I fixed it with mod_arr = np.copy(orig_array).

Comment: perhaps more idiomatically, `mod_arr = orig_array.copy()`

Comment: What do you mean that the function returning `mod_arr, orig_array[:, col_idx]` will then create views? Can these be appended to a list?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50593483/whats-the-difference-between-a-view-and-a-shallow-copy-of-a-numpy-array

Answer (score 0):

When you write `mod_arr = orig_array` that means both variables are referencing to the same memory address. if you modify one the other also modifies. you should use `mod_arr = orig_array.copy()` if you want not to be modified.

Comment: "that means both arrays are referencing to the same memory address" no, **there is only one array**.